# Make a Textbox recognize a url or external link

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to know how can i make that a textbox or a richtextbox recognizes a url within a text in windows phone

My textbox is bonded so i don't know  what the text will be.

Is there a way to make the textbox recognize the url?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing a converter, which does some type of logic based on whatever it is you're trying to accomplish (your question seems a little vague in this sense)

You should look into ValueConverters => http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html